# Python dash gives me an "Error loading layout" how can I solve this?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Hey i am new to Python Dash and I followed the https://dash.plot.ly/installation tutorial.

First I Installed all the libraries with pip in my cmd shell.

After that I created the app.py file and added this code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So far no errors yet.
When I start the server and go to http://127.0.0.1:8050 the webpage gives me 
an error: "Error loading layout".

I tried to figure it out with all the other reports for help but I still cant find the answer.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks alot!

Comment: I am also wondering how one would go about debugging this...

Answer (score 0):

I successfully ran this with no issue, so I would assume that it is an issue with one your modules being incomplete. Try re-installing all the underlying modules (dash, dcc, and html) via pip or conda and see if that clears up the issue.